# Tesseract & Opencv Program image issue show some errors

Tags: opencv, github, ocr, tesseract, leptonica

when i run the exe then show the some errors in tesseract using opencv OCR.
Tesseract : 4.0.0
Laptonica : 1.74.4
Libpng : Libpng1636
Zlib : zlib1211

I use the steps of github project i provide link of that : https://github.com/ghimiredhikura/Install-OpenCV-with-Tesseract-Windows#step-3-install-llpng-and-zlib

> Error in pixReadMemTiff: function not present
>   Error in pixReadMem: tiff: no pix returned
>   Error in pixaGenerateFontFromString: pix not made
>   Error in bmfCreate: font pixa not made
>   Error in pixCreateHeader: width must be > 0
>   Error in pixCreateNoInit: pixd not made
>   Error in pixCreate: pixd not made
>   Error in pixGetData: pix not defined
>   Error in pixGetWpl: pix not defined
>   Error in pixSetYRes: pix not defined
>   Error in pixGetDimensions: pix not defined
>   Error in pixGetColormap: pix not defined
>   Error in pixCopy: pixs not defined
>   Error in pixGetDepth: pix not defined
>   Error in pixGetWpl: pix not defined
>   Error in pixGetYRes: pix not defined
>   Error in pixClone: pixs not defined
>   Please call SetImage before attempting recognition.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UohmQ.png)

Please give me any suggestion about that errors.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You build leptonica without (lib)tiff support and based on error message you use tiff image as input... You can

1. change image format that is supported by your leptonica build (e.g. to png)
2. build leptonica with support of tiff (and other) image format

Comment: thanks for your response but i used already jpg formate file image. i mention image when i asked question.

Comment: But error message is clear: 'Error in pixReadMemTiff: function not present Error in pixReadMem: tiff...', so you "have to" use tiff.
Also tutorial you are referring should support only png for leptonica... So this is real root of your problem. You will need to rebuild leptonica and tesseract - I would suggest to use the latest versions (1.78 for leptonica, and 4.1 for tesseract)

Comment: I have used latest version of leptonica & tesseract but error are same not solved. i have also used cppan for tiff library for leptonica. please let me know any suggestion about that. thank you

Comment: I build leptonica with cppan many times and I NEVER have this kind of error message - because cppan build all leptonica dependencies.